# In jQuery, what's the best way of formatting a number to 2 decimal places?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rounding, decimal-point, number-formatting

This is what I have right now:

```
$("#number").val(parseFloat($("#number").val()).toFixed(2));
```

It looks messy to me.  I don't think I'm chaining the functions correctly.  Do I have to call it for each textbox, or can I create a separate function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 110, accepted):

If you're doing this to several fields, or doing it quite often, then perhaps a plugin is the answer.
Here's the beginnings of a jQuery plugin that formats the value of a field to two decimal places.
It is triggered by the onchange event of the field. You may want something different.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // mini jQuery plugin that formats to two decimal places
    (function($) {
        $.fn.currencyFormat = function() {
            this.each( function( i ) {
                $(this).change( function( e ){
                    if( isNaN( parseFloat( this.value ) ) ) return;
                    this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
                });
            });
            return this; //for chaining
        }
    })( jQuery );

    // apply the currencyFormat behaviour to elements with 'currency' as their class
    $( function() {
        $('.currency').currencyFormat();
    });

</script>   
<input type="text" name="one" class="currency"><br>
<input type="text" name="two" class="currency">
```

Comment: Hi, i would like to know that whether do we need another plugin to currencyFormat()?..

Answer (score 66):

Maybe something like this, where you could select more than one element if you'd like?

```js
$("#number").each(function(){
    $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2));
});
```

Comment: On a side note you shouldn't have duplicate ids in your dom.  Consider changing 'number' to a class.

Comment: @gradbot - nothing about this implies that there is more than one element with id = "number".  It looks like svinto is just using the "each" function as a way to reduce the number of times the magic string "#number" appears in the code.  It is a small (and good, I think) improvement on LainMH's code.  If this formatting only needs to be done on one page, then this is the way I would prefer to do it.  If it needs to be duplicated on more than one page, then I prefer meouw's plugin approach - except extracted out to an external javascript file.

Comment: @DanielSchilling..I assume what gradbot was trying to say was that if you want to apply the same function over multiple input box on a single page then too you cannot provide them the same id or you cannot keep on mentioning every input box's id like this `('#num1,#num2').each(function(){});` .So it would be better to use class approach like this `('.number').each(function(){});`.And provide each input box with a common class -number

Answer (score 4):

We modify a Meouw function to be used with keyup, because when you are using an input it can be more helpful.

Check this:

Hey there!, @heridev and I created a small function in jQuery.

You can try next:

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="one" class="two-digits"><br>
<input type="text" name="two" class="two-digits">​
```

jQuery

```
// apply the two-digits behaviour to elements with 'two-digits' as their class
$( function() {
    $('.two-digits').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().indexOf('.')!=-1){         
            if($(this).val().split(".")[1].length > 2){                
                if( isNaN( parseFloat( this.value ) ) ) return;
                this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
            }  
         }            
         return this; //for chaining
    });
});
```

​
DEMO ONLINE:

http://jsfiddle.net/c4Wqn/

(@heridev, @vicmaster)

Comment: I think you might want to use .change() in place of .keyup()...