# jQuery round decimal to .49 or .99

Tags: jquery, math, floating-point, rounding, decimal

I'm trying to work out how to round a decimal to .49 or .99.

I have found the `toFixed(2)` function, but not sure how to round up or down.

Basically need to get to the closest price point, so for example X.55 would go down to X.49 and X.84 would go up to X.99.

Comment: read [similar concept](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477892/in-jquery-whats-the-best-way-of-formatting-a-number-to-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This doesn’t require jQuery but can be done with plain JavaScript:

```
Math.round(price*2)/2 - 0.01
```

Note to also consider the case where the number would get rounded to 0 (`price` > 0.25) as that would yield -0.01 in this case.

Comment: That works a treat. Nice one! I'll make sure to consider the -0.01 possibility as you point out.

Answer (score 1):

If I had a dollar for every time jQuery made things more obtuse than they needed to be...

```
window.round = function(num) {
    cents = (num * 100) % 100;
    if (cents >= 25 && cents < 75) {
        //round x.25 to x.74 -> x.49
        return Math.floor(num) + 0.49;
    }
    if (cents < 25) {
        //round x.00 to x.24 -> [x - 1].99
        return Math.floor(num) - 0.01;
    }
    //round x.75 to x.99 -> x.99
    return Math.floor(num) + 0.99;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing you cant round/fix to a specific number, you will need to check/caclulate the value, which could mean: rounding up then subtracting 1 or rounding up and subtracting 51.

Answer (score 0):

This does not require jQuery. You just need Math class from javascript also rounding off will require some addtional subtraction since rounding will give nearest decimal

Answer (score 0):

Editing aroth's answer a little bit in order to lets say we also need to round to nearest 5 multiply value

```
window.round = function(num) {
cents = (num * 100) % 100;
if (cents >= 25 && cents < 75) {
    //round x.25 to x.74 -> x.49
    return Math.ceil(num/5)*5  + 0.49;
}
if (cents < 25) {
    //round x.00 to x.24 -> [x - 1].99
    return Math.ceil(num/5)*5  - 0.01;
}
//round x.75 to x.99 -> x.99
return Math.ceil(num/5)*5  + 0.99;
};
```