# Round jQuery Output to 2 Decimal Places

Tags: jquery, html, decimal

I have been trying to get my output decimals to round to 2 places but am not using `.toFixed` or `.round` correctly.

Where is the correct place to put them?

```
$(function(){
    var val     = $('#height-slider').val();
    heightOutput  = $('#height-output');

    heightOutput.html(val);

    $('#height-slider').on('change', function(){
        heightOutput.html(this.value);
        $('#height-output1').html(parseInt(this.value)/2.42868520091);
        $('#height-output2').html(parseInt(this.value)/2.41585201564);
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KMPEX/)

Comment: If you have enough code to make a fiddle, you have enough code to include in your question.

Comment: This might be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431440/jquery-round-decimal-to-49-or-99?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [In jQuery, what's the best way of formatting a number to 2 decimal places?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477892/in-jquery-whats-the-best-way-of-formatting-a-number-to-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/KMPEX/1/

```
$(function(){
        var val     = $('#height-slider').val();
            heightOutput  = $('#height-output');

        heightOutput.html(val);

        $('#height-slider').on('change', function(){
            heightOutput.html(this.value);
            $('#height-output1').html((parseInt(this.value)/2.42868520091).toFixed(2));
            $('#height-output2').html((parseInt(this.value)/2.41585201564).toFixed(2));
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, I was missing a `(` I'll pick this answer as the correct one in 8minutes

Answer (score 2):

`.toFixed(2)` is a method you call on the number. In this case, wrap parentheses around the division operation:

```
$('#height-output1').html((parseInt(this.value)/2.42868520091).toFixed(2));
$('#height-output2').html((parseInt(this.value)/2.41585201564).toFixed(2));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/JQp9c/

`.toFixed(2)` is the appropriate method in this case, but you could use `Math.round()` this way instead:

```
$('#height-output1').html(Math.round(100*parseInt(this.value)/2.42868520091)/100);
$('#height-output2').html(Math.round(100*parseInt(this.value)/2.41585201564)/100);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/fCLWU/

Comment: Thank you, I was missing a `(`

Comment: Always post the code that you've tried; it will usually get you a solution more quickly.