# Convert number to decimal is not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In the below code i have a textbox when i try to enter a number (ie)10 it should convert it to 10.00.But i tried it doesn't work for me and onblur is also not working.pls help me to solve the issue.

```
<script>
function sample(){

    var num = 10;
    var result = num.toFixed(2);
}</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="value"  onblur="sample(this)" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477892/in-jquery-whats-the-best-way-of-formatting-a-number-to-2-decimal-places

Comment: it should working see http://jsfiddle.net/vEtm5/

Comment: Use **parseInt(document.getElementById("value"));** instead of 10 to get the result on value given in TextBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing this

```
function sample() {

              var num = parseFloat(document.getElementById("value").value);//read the textbox value
            var result = num.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("value").value=result;//it will bind the result to the textbox


        }
```

Comment: Pls tell me how to get value from the user

Comment: @user3224577 I have added that code please check it out

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script>
function sample(num){

    var result = num.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('value').value=result; 
}</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="value"  onblur="sample(this.value)" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's must be converted review your code 
try this example it's so close to your code
[W3schools Example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tofixed)

Answer (score 0):

try this

**parseFloat(num).toFixed(2);**

this will 100% works for me..

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It works fine as you need,

```
            function sample() {
                var num = parseInt(document.getElementById("value").value);
                var result = num.toFixed(2);
                document.getElementById("value").value = result;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, It might be helpful for you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#number").each(function(){
  $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2));
});

</script>
```